# Order_By does not seem to work on queryset

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-models

I have my models set up as:

```
class F(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    min=models.IntegerField()
    max=models.IntegerField()
    duration=models.IntegerField() #in minutes

class RF(models.Model):
    f=models.ForeignKey(F)
    rid=models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Now I am trying to get a list of all "F" which is associated with a given RF object in desc order of max value. So I have in my view as :

```
flist=RF.objects.all().order_by('-f__max')
```

However this gives the list in default order rather than the "max" value.
How to get this working?

Thanks

Comment: Should work. Could you provide some sample data and the output you're getting?

Comment: Thanks I had messed up my views, it is working fine now.